# Using regex to extract text inside two characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract some text from a set of strings. I have three cases on those strings

- X | A | Y
- A | Y
- A

Where A is the text I want to extract. I've tried using `(?:\|)(.*?)(?:\|)` which only works on the first case and have been trying to combine several options I've seen in other questions but no luck so far, if I match a case, the other cases won't be matched.

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Can't you just split on `|`?

Comment: @Rawing yeah, I can't split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try:

```
(?:.*?\|([^\|]+)\|.*?)|(^[^\|]+)
```

The result will be in either capturing group 1 or group 2

Comment: This one did it, I have to make a bit more of processing to get the best result out of the 2 - 3 resulting groups but it's ok. Thank you!

Comment: @JhonAlx You can just concatenate the two capturing groups, as one will be empty.  And there are only 2, not 2-3

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work  `(?:^|(?<=\|))\s*(A)\s*(?:(?=\|)|$)`

It finds the `A` substring in capture group 1

This is definitely a case where you need assertions.
I don't think it will work without them.

Explained:

```
 (?:
      ^                             # BOS
   |                              # or,
      (?<= \| )                     # | behind
 )
 \s*                           # optional wsp trim
 ( A )                         # (1), What your looking for
 \s*                           # optional wsp trim
 (?:
      (?= \| )                      # | ahead
   |                              # or,
      $                             # EOS
 )
```